# Liebesleid (Love's Sorrow) - Kreisler (arr. Rachmaninoff), tie or slur?

Tags: piano, slurs, ties

I'm currently learning Liebesleid (Love's Sorrow) - Kreisler (arr. Rachmaninoff) and I'm a bit confused about the last tie/slur of this part. Is it the E that's tied or is it the A that's slurred?

At first I thought it was 3 ties but I think the last one is a slur?

[image: description]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's definitely a slur from the A to the G♮, and for at least a few reasons:

1. The beginning of this slur/tie is *above* the initial E. Engravers make mistakes, but that's a hard mistake to rationalize.
2. The [first edition of the score](http://ks.imslp.net/files/imglnks/usimg/0/0d/IMSLP438425-SIBLEY1802.30663.1f5c-39087013809886alt2_score.pdf) makes it pretty clear that the A on beat 1 ultimately moves to the F♯ in the next measure, thereby connecting this A to G♮:

[image]

3. And if it were a tie connecting two Es, the engraver likely would have just written a dotted half note.

Answer (score 1):

That last E is definitely not tied to the one before it in that second bar shown. If it was, the 'tie' line would start below the first E. It's a slur line, referring to the A>G♯>G♮ chromatic run. Also, since both Es are shown with stems down, it would have made more sense to write a dotted minim at the beginning, had it supposedly been a note lasting the whole bar.